# Фреймворк Vaadin

Tags: веб-программирование, java, vaadin

Наткнулся на [статью](http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/webdev/115999/) про фреймворк Vaadin, про который раньше не слышал. Бегло ознакомился с основными особенностями, посмотрел демо и коды. Как мне показалось Vaadin удобнее для разработки и лучше продуман, даже чем привычный мне JSF 2.0.
Но возникает вопрос, почему Vaadin не очень известен и востребован, может я не заметил каких-то неприятных особенностей?
Что вы думаете про Vaadin?

Comment: <quote>
Считается преимуществом, при использовании Vaadin приходится программировать только на одном языке — Java, то есть не надо заморачиваться с XML, JavaScript, Html и т.д.
</quote>
Я на Java не пишу, но идея написания веб-приложения на одном языке выглядит провальной. Ещё куда ни шло если бы там было несколько DSL-лей, но на Java, как я понял, с этим не очень.

Comment: Мне эта идея провальной не кажется, как и множеству разработчиков, которые используют GWT. А в Vaadin по сравнению с GWT еще и упрощен механизм обращения к серверу. Я, например, привык работать со Swing и такой подход вполне по душе.

Comment: Всё же плохо, что всё на Java. Могут быть проблемы с какими-то вещами, которые не предусмотрены Vaadin.. хотя, может и есть какие-то предусмотренные способы кастомизации

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Неизвестен" и "невостребован" можно сказать про множество фреймворков, популярность набирается со временем. Spring,JMF,EMF то же не сразу стали известными и популярными =)

Answer (score 0):

Почему vaadin не стал стандартом JEE раз он на java?
Мне ближе и понятнее JSF = чистая MVC. UI отдельно (xhtml) логика приложения отдельно (java).Нет завязки на сторонние продукты вроде GWT.Далее в JSF вы произвольно можете применять чистый html и html5 а так же все что нужно на клиенте можете написать на JavaScript. Ajaks поддерживается с версии 2.0. Более того вы вольны выбирать любую из существующих реализаций стандарта JSF. Либо несколько реализаций совместно.Очень гибкий инструмент JSF! Vaadin  не пробовал но надо посмотреть ....

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я знаю, минус в том, что страницы, генерируемые Vaadin'ом, не индексируются поисковиками, ибо сплошной JavaScript...